# Recieving a "Cannot GET /login" error when navigating to route "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login" on my live server. "npm start" working fine though

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, react-router-dom

I've built an app that is running well when on the server generated from the npm start command, but when I set up a server with npm live-server, or a python simple HTTPserver, I'm getting this error when I navigate to the /login route.

Saying "Cannot GET /login". But at no point do I send a get request from what I can tell. When I navigate to the /login route, all that should appear is a form that takes in user info and sends a post request to get a token.

Here are all of my user Actions in my UserActions.js file. As you can see it's very minimal (I don't even have a /register, this is because I only have 1 admin user already in the database and have no need to register)

usrerActions.js

```
import {
  SET_USER,
  SET_ERRORS,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
  LOADING_UI,
  SET_UNAUTHENTICATED
} from "../types";
import axios from 'axios'

export const loginUser = (userData, history) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI });
    axios
      .post("/login", userData)
      .then((res) => {
        const FBIdToken = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`;
        localStorage.setItem("FBIdToken", `Bearer ${res.data.token}`);
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = FBIdToken;
        // dispatch(getUserData());
        dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS })
        history.push("/");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ 
            type: SET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.response.data
            })
      });
}

export const logoutUser = () => (dispatch) => {
  localStorage.removeItem('FBIdToken');
  delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
  dispatch({ type: SET_UNAUTHENTICATED })
}

export const getUserData = () => (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('/user')
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: SET_USER,
            payload: res.data
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

My app.js with routes

```
...

const token = localStorage.FBIdToken;
if (token) {
  const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
  if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    window.location.href = "/login";
  } else {
    store.dispatch({ type: SET_AUTHENTICATED });
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;
  }
}
function App() {
  document.documentElement.classList.remove("nav-open");
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.body.classList.add("index");
    return function cleanup() {
      document.body.classList.remove("index");
    };
  });
  return (
    // <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <div className="main">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
            <Route exact path="/products" component={products} />
            <Route exact path="/retreats" component={retreats} />
            <Route exact path="/tarot" component={tarot} />
            <Route
              path="/artist"
              render={props => <ProfilePage {...props} />}
            />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={login} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
    // </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And my login.jsx page component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

...

export class login extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      errors: {}
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.UI.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.UI.errors })
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }
    this.props.loginUser(userData, this.props.history);
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    // loading was before: { classes, UI: { loading } }
    const { classes, loading } = this.props;
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
      <IndexNavbar />
      <ProfilePageHeader />
      <Grid container className={classes.form}>
        <Grid item sm />
        <Grid item sm>
          <ChangeHistoryIcon />
          <Typography variant="h3" className={classes.pageTitle}>
            Login
          </Typography>
          <form noValidate onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
              id="email"
              name="email"
              type="email"
              label="Email"
              className={classes.textField}
              helperText={errors.email}
              error={errors.email ? true : false}
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              fullWidth
            />
            <TextField
              id="password"
              name="password"
              type="password"
              label="Password"
              className={classes.textField}
              helperText={errors.password}
              error={errors.password ? true : false}
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              fullWidth
            />
            {errors.general && (
              <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.customError}>
                {errors.general}
              </Typography>
            )}
            <Button
              type="submit"
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              className={classes.button}
            >
              Login
              {loading && (
                <CircularProgress size={30} className={classes.progress} />
              )}
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm />
      </Grid>
    </>
    );
  }
}

login.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  UI: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
  UI: state.UI
});

const mapActionsToProps = {
  loginUser
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(withStyles(styles)(login));
```

Does anybody know why I get this error when I'm obviously sending a post request?

### any help is greatly appreciated!

ANDit was brought to my attention that it might be an issue with my backennd not rendering the index file? I'm not sure what to do here. this is my backend index file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = require('express')();

const FBAuth = require('./util/fbAuth')

const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());


const { getAllPosts, createOnePost, getThePost, deletePost, uploadImage } = require('./handlers/posts');
const { login } = require('./handlers/users');

// Posts Routes

app.get('/posts', getAllPosts);
app.get('/post/:postId', getThePost);
app.post("/post", FBAuth, createOnePost);
app.delete('/post/:postId', FBAuth, deletePost);
app.post('/post/:postId/image', FBAuth, uploadImage);
//TODO update post

// Login Route
app.post('/login', login)

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Comment: when running live server, when the request is made from browser, "/login" does not call your react code, but instead calls your node server endpoint and tries to find "/login" GET, as request from browser tab is a get request.

Make sure that your node server `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`  renders the index.html page which has react app.js hooked into it.

Comment: Hey thanks, I see what you're saying. I still don't quite understand how to change my code though. Should I change the App.js routes to do this? Or you mean on my back end? where would that go?

Comment: can you check what your npm start command actually does?
normally, when we use react with node, what we do is we run node.js apis on a specific port and then we render index.html file from static folder ,
have you placed your react code base in a static folder being renderd via node?

Comment: npm live server just serves what content is available and npm start possibly is creating a react bundle for you...

i do not think using npm live server is correct choice here..

Comment: I used 'npm run build' to build the app before launching it in a server. That's when the error comes. These are both the default scripts that come with create-react-app. And I also tried a python server with the same issue.

Comment: once you do npm run build, then you will get a public folder correct?

Comment: No actually that script makes a build folder

Comment: now you will need to serve the build folder..
navigate to build folder and run the the following:

npm install serve -g
serve ./ -p 3000

This will serve your react code..
you have specified a node endpoint react codebase right?for making api call?what is that?

Comment: so the flow is like follows:
1. you build your react code using npm run build which creates a build folder.
2. we serve the folder on a specific port and then localhost url with the specified port.
3. your  react app points to a node endpoint , which you are running using npm-live server
4. your react app will call your node.js app based on the url specifed in your react codebase

Comment: Okay so, did all of that. server was running again. But then when navigating to /login,I got a 404 err

Comment: which port is your build folder served on?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/login..u tried this link right?

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you're using react router dom. Are you using < Link to='/login' >? or are you using another way that actually sends a get request such as an a tag? 
React Router Dom needs you to use their components to navigate on the react side of things.